# loop through all files in directory bash

Tags: bash, file, loops, directory

I know this question has been asked before. However, none of the examples seems to work for me. Hence:
I've got files all of the type
    XXXX1.txt
    XXXX2.txt
    XXXX3.txt
    ...
    XXXX9.txt in the same directory.

Now I want to grep a certain value from each file using bash:

```
for file in *$i.txt
do
   for ((i = 1; i < 10; i++))
   do
   grep "energy" *.txt >> energies.txt
   done
done
```

The code and grep works fine without any errors, but I always get the grep from the first iteration, the first energy printed 9 times. It never looks at the others. I know these kind of loops are complicated in bash. However, please don't suggest to move all files into separate directories and loop through them.

Comment: For each file that `*$i.txt` matches (whatever `$i` is) you run `grep` nine times on *all* files that match `*.txt`. Did you perhaps mean `grep "energy" "$file"`? But why use two loops?! Why not just `grep "energy" XXXX*.txt`?

Comment: You can't use `$i` in the start of the loop if you define it inside...

Comment: I think this question needs to be clarified *a lot* before it can be answered. What's the actual goal? What's the value of `$i`? What are the files' names? What's the outer loop for? What's the inner loop for? What's so magic about the number 9?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such complicated (and wrong) nested loops.
Try this only command:

```
grep -h "energy" *{1..9}.txt >> energies.txt
```

Comment: this may throw an error if file is not present `grep: *3.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: @BigDataLearner You are right, but that was the OP's original intent. I respected it.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need content of file(s):

```
grep -h "energy" *[1-9].txt >> energies.txt
```

if you need file name with content:

```
grep -H "energy" *[1-9].txt >> energies.txt
```

Comment: Add the `-h` option to `grep` if you don't want the filenames. If you need them, even when `*[1-9].txt` matches only one file, add the `-H` option.

Comment: @xhienne - great - I updated answer - I learnt this option too : ) - Thanks